# Per pool php.ini on php-fpm

Tags: php, php-fpm

Anyone have any idea how to do this in tittle ? Or at least something similar (enable/disable functions that are usualy in php.ini)

My pool now looks like this

```
[amar]
listen = 127.0.0.1:11000
user = amar
group = amar
request_slowlog_timeout = 5s
slowlog = /var/log/slowlog-amar.log
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_requests = 500
include = /etc/php5/fpm/fpm.d/common.conf
```

and its located in fpm.d/pools which is included in defauld php5-fpm.conf

I found something about php_defines but I have no clue how to implement this

ty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this with something like:

```
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /home/amar/web
php_admin_value[allow_url_fopen] = 0
```

etc...